# How can I set up a simple test with Cabal?

Tags: testing, haskell, cabal

I have a Haskell project and Cabal package-description that allows me to build and install my package with

```
$ cabal configure
$ cabal build
$ cabal install
```

But what about `cabal test`? Cabal's help says to configure a test suite with UserHooks, but how can I do that?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As Duncan mentioned in Greg's answer, Cabal-1.10 has support for test suites out of the box.

The [manual](http://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#test-suites) seems to have the best information that's I've found regarding how to make use of this.

Here's a snippet from the manual which shows how to use the `exitcode-stdio` test type:

**foo.cabal**

```
Name:           foo
Version:        1.0
License:        BSD3
Cabal-Version:  >= 1.9.2
Build-Type:     Simple

Test-Suite test-foo
    type:       exitcode-stdio-1.0
    main-is:    test-foo.hs
    build-depends: base
```

**test-foo.hs:**

```
module Main where

import System.Exit (exitFailure)

main = do
    putStrLn "This test always fails!"
    exitFailure
```

Comment: Hmm, looks like a typo in the manual.  Shouldn't that read `Cabal-Version: >= 1.10` ?  Or will earlier cabals harmlessly ignore it?

Comment: Err, nevermind, it says it right there in the manual: "Using test suite sections requires at least Cabal version 1.9.2"

Comment: note that in order for the test suite's dependencies to *install*, you must run `cabal install --enable-tests`. Then you can run `cabal test` to run your tests.

Answer (score 13):

For one approach, see [Setting up a simple test with Cabal](http://gbacon.blogspot.com/2009/06/setting-up-simple-test-with-cabal.html).

This approach has drawbacks, and there's an [open Cabal ticket](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/hackage/ticket/215) that suggests being able to specify tests more directly, *e.g.*,

```
test
  test-is: Test
  build-depends: QuickCheck
  hs-source-dirs: tests src
```

Comment: This feature will be in Cabal-1.10

Comment: @Duncan Great news and great that you're contributing here!